# Should ObjectDisposedException be thrown from a property get

Tags: .net, encapsulation, idisposable

So according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception.aspx `ObjectDisposedException` is:

> The exception that is thrown when an operation is performed on a disposed object.

So since a property get should not be changing state it is not really "performing an operation". So should an `ObjectDisposedException` be thrown then someone accesses a property set on a disposed object?

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, any usage of a disposed object is really invalid.  As such, throwing on a property get wouldn't be unreasonable.

That being said, this could, potentially, lead to extra overhead which might be enough to prevent inlining of the getter by the JIT, so in practice, it may not be worth adding the disposal checks if the getter will succeed anyways.  If the property getter will fail and throw after disposal, then I would definitely add the check, so the exception will be meaningful and not unrelated to the type.

> So should an ObjectDisposedException be thrown then someone accesses a property set on a disposed object?

I definitely think throwing on a property *setter* is appropriate, if an object has been disposed.

Comment: +1 only throw when you need to throw, otherwise it's a performance overhead

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the imperative to throw an `ObjectDisposedException` if an object is used after disposal is not nearly so strong as the imperative not to have such usage cause *any other exception*.  In cases where meeting the latter requirement would require that an object ensure that it wasn't disposed before taking some action, having it throw `ObjectDisposedException` when used improperly may be essentially "free".  On the other hand, I don't think it should be necessary for an object to carry around a `Disposed` flag in cases where it wouldn't otherwise have to care about whether it was disposed or not (e.g. `Enumerable<T>.Empty.GetEnumerator()` should be able to return a singleton enumerator instance whose `MoveNext()` always returns `false` without regard for whether it's been disposed).